# How to make valid JSON Response from http POST method's Response?

Tags: webservices, rest, apexrest

How to remove the escape characters"" from the Response and the the double quotes at the beginning and the end from the Response ? please check the expected valid response in the below.
**Code :**

```java
    @HttpPost
    global static string dopost() {                
              RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
              RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
              Case tkt= (Case)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),Case.class);
              system.debug(tkt);
              try {              
                insert tkt;
              }
              catch(DmlException e) {
             return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
        }      
             Case insertedCase = [Select Id,CaseNumber,Subject,Status,Reason,Origin from Case Where Id =:tkt.Id];       
                 return JSON.serialize(insertedCase);         
    }
```

**Response :**

> "{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000SzkMOAAZ"},"Id":"5002800000SzkMOAAZ","CaseNumber":"00001081","Subject":"TWX-Request","Status":"New","Reason":"Deviation","Origin":"TWX"}"

**Valid Response to parse :**

> {"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000SzkMOAAZ"},"Id":"5002800000SzkMOAAZ","CaseNumber":"00001081","Subject":"TWX-Request","Status":"New","Reason":"Deviation","Origin":"TWX"}

Comment: Where are you consuming this service, in or out of Salesforce

Comment: Out of Salesforce @Rahul Sharma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting proper `Content-Type` response headers. In your response to Ashwani, you stated that you added `res.addHeader()`, but that line will not make much sense, if you are not returning the `RestContext.response`, as is clearly the case judging from your code.

What you are returning is simply a string created by `JSON.serialize()` function. Would not make much of a difference if you returned any literal string for that matter. So whatever you return as response that way is ignoring the context of the RestContext.response.

What I would suggest is that you modify your `HttpPost` method, firstly by changing the return type from string to void. And secondly by not returning any explicit values, but instead setting the values you wanted to return into the `RestContext` response body.

E.g.

```java
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {                
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    
        Case tkt = (Case)JSON.deserialize(req.requestBody.toString(),Case.class);
    
        try {              
            insert tkt;
    
            Case insertedCase = [Select Id,CaseNumber,Subject,Status,Reason,Origin from Case Where Id =:tkt.Id];       
            
            //return JSON.serialize(insertedCase); 
            res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(insertedCase));
            res.statusCode = 200;  
        }
        catch(DmlException e) {
    
            //return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
            res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{ "errorMessage" : "' +e.getMessage()+'" }');
            res.statusCode = 400;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. Few things you can do to avoid this:

1. When you send request to this web-service, make sure you set `content-type` header as `application/json`. And vice-verse using the `RestResponse` class variable `headers`.
2. If above solution doesn't work. Find the similar method in external requester which can convert string to json or remove escape slashes and then parse that json string to relevant object.

Comment: I have added  res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'); //Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: But of no use... Still am getting  Raw Response as : "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Case\",\"url\":\"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5002800000SztelAAB\"},\"Id\":\"5002800000SztelAAB\",\"CaseNumber\":\"00001090\",\"Subject\":\"First  NNTest\",\"Status\":\"New\",\"Reason\":\"Deviation\",\"Origin\":\"Web\"}"

Comment: How do we do it for a LIST of Cases and Responses.